# What closings can I use to convey friendship but not desire?

Tags: email

I recently received and email from someone regarding potential business. However, a small part of me suspects that they may have an alternate motive for contacting me.

Common business closings, such as regards, can come across as a bit stiff.  Yet, it seems the casualness of our original interaction is likely one of the reasons they wanted to do business with me in the first place.

#### As such, I'm looking for a closing that can convey a sense of informality and warmth, without possibly expressing desire.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask where you're from, and where the receiver is from? This can make a big difference in this regard.

Comment: @CLockeWork Boston, MA

Comment: OK, not quite sure how it goes in America. In the UK, `Kind regards` is certainly formal but also warm. `Cheers` is common work-casual and `Thanks` is also a great way to go.

Comment: I would have went with `thanks` or `good luck` if appropriate to the content of the email.  Here 'Best' heavily used in business here, and thus has a formal connotation.  `Cheers` is casual with a hint of warmth.

Comment: I tend to favour Cheers and Thanks in work, personaly I find Regards too formal.

Comment: @CLockeWork I'll end a message with `thanks`, but still close with `regards` as I often feel the need to convey respect when talking to other scientists, and `thanks` on it's own can come across as presumptuous and terse.

Comment: I agree; it's very much down to who you're talking to. I tend towards `Thanks` when my email is asking for something, though dependant on how much and I'm asking for, and from whom, I may use `Thank you` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something on the lines of

"Looking forward to doing business with you

With Kind Regards

Your name"

Or maybe "Best Regards".

Consider looking at [this](http://www.forbes.com/sites/susanadams/2013/09/27/57-ways-to-sign-off-on-an-email/) list for some nice suggestions.

Comment: thanks, I swear I use to have that list bookmarked!  Anyway, I settled on Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when greeting across cultures.  Many years ago, I was learning German.  My prof told me that "*Wie gehts?*" was replacing the more formal "*Wie geht es Ihnen?*", especially among close acquaintances.  Soon after, I happened to visit my "uncle" (really, a close family friend), who emigrated to the U.S. from Germany as a teen soon after WWII.  I greeted him with a jaunty "*Wie gehts?*", hoping to impress him with my slick German.  He was mortified!  After growling something in German, he informed me that "*Wie gehts?*" was a greeting that only very low-class Germans would use, and that using it with one's uncle was insulting.  (Ach, those class-conscious Germans!)

My point is, even when you think you know the culture, I would err on the side of formality for a first email.  Your greetings can gradually get less formal as you trade correspondence.